# Postgres SELECT values where only some columns respect WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that I wish to select from.  I want to select the same column twice, once with some date based filtering in the WHERE clause, and again without the filtering.  How can I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: With 1000 rep I'm surprised you haven't written a better question. Table definitions/sample data, PostgreSQL version, desired results, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `UNION` query, possibly with a CTE.

You haven't provided table definitions so I can't provide real SQL. You're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM thetable
WHERE ...datefilter ...
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM thetable
WHERE ... otherfilter...;
```

You may find common table expressions ("WITH" queries) useful too.